# Reuse local Swift package in multiple targets

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I need to reuse local Swift packages in multiple targets. They are all part of the same workspace which looks something like this

```
- Workspace
  - ProjectA
    - TargetA1 depends on PackageA
    - TargetA2 depends on PackageA and PackageB
  - ProjectB
    - TargetB1 depends on PackageA
  - ProjectC, etc...
  - Modules
    - PackageA
    - PackageB
```

The package build products are added under the individual targets `General > Frameworks and Libraries` dependencies. Now when I trigger the build, I get

```
Multiple commands produce '.../Modules/PackageA' etc...
```

which is somewhat understandable, I hoped Xcode would be smart enough to not build the package over and over again, and even if, I don't understand why that would result in an error in the first place.

Is there a reasonable solution to this?

I don't want to start creating static library targets again or create a separate repository just to be able to import it via a package dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found a somewhat satisfactory answer to this.

First, ***prevent SPM from choosing the library type itself*** and declare 2 separate build products in the package you want to share:

```
...
products: [
    .library(name: "PackageA", type: .dynamic, targets: ["PackageA"]),
    .library(name: "PackageAStatic", type: .static, targets: ["PackageA"])
],
...
```

One explicitly `.dynamic` and the other explicitly `.static`. Now depending on the target you want to use this package in, link the correct one (either dynamic or static). This seems to resolve this issue for me.

Comment: When I tried this I got this error:

Swift package target ‘PackageA’ is linked as a static library by ‘MyApp’ and ‘PackageA’, but cannot be built dynamically because there is a package product with the same name. Did you actually get this working? If so, how did you avoid this problem?

Comment: hey @JimRoepcke, did you find any solution for your problem?